# How do I catch object creation using a proxy?

Tags: javascript, proxy

Thank you for taking the time to read my problem. A website's javascript I'm reverse engineering executes the following line:

```
this.socket = new WebSocket(o.host)
```

The line is buried in functions of other functions, etc. so I am not able to access it normally during runtime. I would like to use a Proxy object to "inject" code whenever new Websocket() is called in order to notify me of its creation and save it to a global variable I would prepare prior.

My greasemonkey script would look something like this:

```
var caught_socket; // prepare variable

handler = {
  apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    console.log("WebSocket was created!");
    caught_socket = target;
  }
}

WebSocket = new Proxy(WebSocket, handler);
```

This obviously does not work and I would be grateful for any help or demonstration of how Proxies actually work!

Comment: Have you tried [construct()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/construct)?

Comment: Don't forget to do something like `Websocket.prototype.constructor = Websocket` after overwriting the global `Websocket` variable. Otherwise scripts might still access the original constructor and get confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Proxy.construct()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/construct) instead, it will execute when `new` is called.

```js
// Create a new WebSocket proxy
WebSocket = new Proxy(WebSocket, {
  construct: (target, args) => {
    console.log('New WebSocket Instance!')
    return new target(...args)
  }
})

// Test the WebSocket proxy by connecting to a remote server
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org')

// Listen for an open connection
// Send a message to the connection
ws.addEventListener('open', () => {
  console.log('Connection Open!')
  ws.send('hello')
})

// Listen for messages from the remote server
ws.addEventListener('message', msg => console.log('Response:', msg.data))
```

If you add a second proxy both proxies execute:

```js
// Create a new WebSocket proxy
WebSocket = new Proxy(WebSocket, {
  construct: (target, args) => {
    console.log('New WebSocket Instance!')
    return new target(...args)
  }
})

WebSocket = new Proxy(WebSocket, {
  construct: (target, args) => {
    console.log('New WebSocket Override!')
    return new target(...args)
  }
})

// Test the WebSocket proxy by connecting to a remote server
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org')

// Listen for an open connection
// Send a message to the connection
ws.addEventListener('open', () => {
  console.log('Connection Open!')
  ws.send('hello')
})

// Listen for messages from the remote server
ws.addEventListener('message', msg => console.log('Response:', msg.data))
```

You could even return a completely different class:

```js
class MyCoolWebSocket {
  addEventListener(event, callback) {
    console.log('override event:', event)
  }
}


// Create a new WebSocket proxy
WebSocket = new Proxy(WebSocket, {
  construct: (target, args) => {
    console.log('New WebSocket Instance!')
    return new WebSocket(...args)
  }
})

// Create a new WebSocket proxy
WebSocket = new Proxy(WebSocket, {
  construct: (target, args) => {
    console.log('Greasemonkey override!')
    return new MyCoolWebSocket(...args)
  }
})

// Test the WebSocket proxy by connecting to a remote server
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org')

// Listen for an open connection
// Send a message to the connection
ws.addEventListener('open', () => {
  console.log('Connection Open!')
  ws.send('hello')
})

// Listen for messages from the remote server
ws.addEventListener('message', msg => console.log('Response:', msg.data))
```

Comment: The code in your answer indeed worked. I removed the ws variable so I would catch the WebSocket created by the website's script but it didn't fire off the Proxy. I put a breakpoint on the line that calls new WebSocket to ensure that the line is actually called and it is. I'm going out of the question's scope, but is it possible that the website "clears any proxy", has some sort of other anti-debugging code hidden somewhere?
http://i.imgur.com/1WDud1e.png (This is how the surrounding code looks)

Comment: I was just trying to ask if there is a possibility that the website's javascript "disables" the proxy I have created prior to their script running, since new WebSocket is clearly called but the Proxy handler isn't firing up.

Comment: Yeah it's possible... We just did it, so there is no reason that the website isn't doing the same...

Comment: I might take that back... It looks like if there is a second proxy both proxies execute.

Comment: Ah. I pasted your code into the console itself and it catches the WebSocket creation. I'm not sure why the Greasemonkey script didnt't work, even though I ensured it ran, but you answered my question perfectly. Thank you!
The Greasemonkey script: http://i.imgur.com/XLNb5LG.png
It ran since the "script injected" showed up but it never caught the websocket creation.
Pasting in the console works perfectly: http://i.imgur.com/It3Uako.png

Comment: @Kaiju I added a third example that could explain why its not running in Greasemonkey.